# Running VQE code using qiskit_nature on IBM computers

Tags: vqe, ibm-quantum-devices

$\texttt{qiskit_nature}$ no longer has the $\texttt{runtime}$ feature and $\texttt{VQEClient}$ function that was used to run a VQE code on one of the IBM computers. I could not find any easy migration guide on the Qiskit website. Could anybody please suggest how to do it?